# How to use try catch in this situation

Tags: php, try-catch

I would like to delete other relations even if any of the previous deletions fail. I have used a lot of try/catch to achieve this. Is there a way I can reduce the amount of try-catch in my code or do it without try-catch?

```
    public function delete_live_event(Request $request){
        try{
            $user = User::find($request->auth_user_id);

            if(!$request->journey_item_id){
                return response()->json(['StatusMessage' => 'Bir hata oluştu !', 'StatusCode' => 401,'error'=>'live_event_id gönderilmedi'], 401);
            }
            $journey_item = JourneyItem::find($request->journey_item_id);
            if ($journey_item == null) {
                return response()->json(['StatusMessage' =>  __('contents.not_found'), 'StatusCode' => 404], 404);
            }

            /** Assigned Users deleted **/
            try{
                UserJourney::where('as_journey_id',$journey_item->journey->id)->delete();
            }catch (\Exception $e){ //log 
            }

            /** journey deleted **/
            try{
                $journey_item->journey()->delete();
            }catch (\Exception $e){
               //Log
            }

            /** content deleted **/
            try{
                $journey_item->content()->delete();
            }catch (\Exception $e){//Log
            }

            /** notifications deleted **/
            try{
                UserJourneyItemNotification::where('as_journey_item_id', $journey_item->id)->delete();
            }catch (\Exception $e){//Log
            }

            /** item deleted **/
            try{
                $journey_item->item()->delete();
            }catch (\Exception $e){//Log
            }

            /** journey_item deleted **/
            $journey_item->delete();

            return response()->json(['StatusMessage' => 'Live event is deleted succesfuly', 'StatusCode' => 200], 200);
        }catch (\Exception $e){
            //TODO error log
            return response()->json(['StatusMessage' => 'Bir hata oluştu !', 'StatusCode' => 400], 401);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try / Catch is usually used in a situation where you want to catch an error in order to stop further processing.  If the each of the items in your list can be deleted, even if the others cannot be deleted, then there is no reason to use try/catch at all.

You also do not need to wrap your main function in try/catch block, as the only failure that would occur within that code is if you called a method that did not exist in your object. That would be a code failure, which would require correction. This is not the type of error that you would want to allow processing to continue, as the missing method is a code bug and should be corrected.

Comment: Thanks for reply, if i want to make log when i take an error, can i use catch block?

Comment: Yes you can.  But I would recommend you apply the try/catch within each method.  Always try to use try/catch at the lowest level possible from a transaction point of view.

Comment: So is the method right to be using try/catch for each deletion? I understood from you that I just need to remove top try/catch in my main function

Comment: Yes just remove the try/catch from the main function, as it is serving no purpose.  If you wrote the delete method - then you should also move the try/catch to the delete method, but if you are calling a standard PHP delete method, which it looks like you are, then leave the it where it is.